# Syntax highlighting for not empty line starting with a space, but only if the previous line did not end with "="

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am currently working on a custom syntax highlighting for vim. I want to highlight lines starting with a space, but only if they contain any letters or numbers.

I could achieve this result with the syn match `'^ .*.[a-zA-Z].*'`, but I want the highlight to be working only if the previous line does not end with a "=".
Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample text to test the regex you want to build :

```
this line doesn't begin with a space
 this line begins with a space and the previous line doesn't end with =
 this line begins with a space and the previous line ends with =
```

The set of characters `[a-zA-Z]` can be expressed with the atom `\a`.
So your regex can be rewritten like this :

```
^ .*.\a.*
```

Now your regex uses the `^` character, which stands for a beginning of a line. The problem is it can only be used at the beginning of the regex. To describe a beginning of line anywhere inside the regex, you have to use `\_^`.

Finally, you don't want the previous line to begin with the character `=`.
This can be expressed with the following regex (in very magic mode) :

```
(\=\n)@<!
```

The end result is :

```
(\=\n)@<!\_^ .*.\a.*
```

Or if you want to be sure the very magic mode is enabled :

```
\v(\=\n)@<!\_^ .*.\a.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

O.k., now seriously. This is only for the starting space.

```
syntax match WhiteSpaceWithoutPrecedingEqualSign /=\@<!\n^ \S/hs=s+1,he=e-1
hi WhiteSpaceWithoutPrecedingEqualSign guibg=blue
```

This is for the line.

```
syntax match WhiteSpaceWithoutPrecedingEqualSign /=\@<!\n^ \S.*/hs=s+1
hi WhiteSpaceWithoutPrecedingEqualSign guibg=blue
```

- [`:h pattern`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html)
- [`:h syntax`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html)